# how to disable systemd auto unmount of manually mounted partitions

Tags: linux, partitioning, mount, ntfs, systemd

I've recently made a systemd unit  that runs a simple bash script to  solve a bug in the NTFS mount driver.
the partition is shared with windows, so if it is hibernated I am unable to mount it `rw`.
And it does not handle properly the `errors=--remount-ro` parameter (in the fstab options section) , so I wrote a script to handle this (temporarily).

except, systemd seems to unmount the "manually" mounted partition when starting the service.
Is this standard functionality of systemd? how do i disable it?

relevant information:

```
systemctl status SHAREDFILES-mount.service

    ● SHAREDFILES-mount.service - mount SHAREDFILES on boot
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/SHAREDFILES-mount.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Tue 2019-01-29 13:15:15 -02; 2h 23min ago
 Main PID: 992 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

jan 29 13:15:09 hosthame systemd[1]: Starting mount SHAREDFILES on boot...
jan 29 13:15:13 hosthame ntfs-3g[1302]: Version 2017.3.23 integrated FUSE 28
jan 29 13:15:13 hosthame ntfs-3g[1302]: Mounted /dev/sda4 (Read-Write, label "SHAREDFILES", NTFS 3.1)
jan 29 13:15:13 hosthame ntfs-3g[1302]: Cmdline options: rw,uid=1000,guid=username,umask=002
jan 29 13:15:13 hosthame ntfs-3g[1302]: Mount options: rw,guid=username,allow_other,nonempty,relatime,default_permissions,fsname=/dev/sda4,blkdev,blksize=4096
jan 29 13:15:13 hosthame ntfs-3g[1302]: Global ownership and permissions enforced, configuration type 7
jan 29 13:15:14 hosthame ntfs-3g[1302]: Unmounting /dev/sda4 (SHAREDFILES)
jan 29 13:15:15 hosthame systemd[1]: Started mount SHAREDFILES on boot
```

script:

```bsh
#try mounting normally (windows not hibernated)
mount -U 'disk-uid' --target /path/to/mountpoint -o uid=username,guid=username,umask=002 && exit;
 #mount as ro (windows hibernated)
    sudo mount -ro --source $( eval $(blkid | grep SHAREDFILES | grep -Eo "UUID=\"\w+\"" ) && blkid -U "$UUID" ) --target /path/to/mountpoint -o uid=username,guid=username,umask=0002 && exit;
```

```
lsb_release  -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Comment: Is that $(eval) just a complex way of writing `--source LABEL=SHAREDFILES`?

Comment: (it's been a long time since I've had this problem, so not sure) @user1686 probably, yes

Comment: Have you been able to find solution? Can you please post answers? I have issue when service (type=simple) at startup calls python script and mount partition... and for no obvious reason getting same msg from ntfs-3g: Unmounting...  (probably automatically upon completion of the service runtime). Forking service leaves partition in place ok.

Comment: @adspx5 I think the NTFS bug was patched, but I cannot confirm right now as I do not use a setup like this anymore. I can try it later if you want.

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested in the `automount` feature:

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.automount.html#

**Systemd and Mounting**

The title of the question is misleading. Let's start there.

Systemd is not directly responsible for mounting drives. It was intended to schedule other services, such as `mount`.

Since the dawn of time, persistent mount points have been manually written in the `/etc/fstab` file.

`mount -a` loads every mount point listed in `/etc/fstab`, so systemd calls `mount -a` at boot (docs don't say otherwise).

To edit, run `sudo nano /etc/fstab` or `sudo gedit /etc/fstab`.

- For anyone who doesn't have `sudo` on their machine: use `su -c=/usr/bin/nano /etc/fstab`. If this path to nano doesn't work, find where yours is with `where nano`.

**Mount files**

Systemd also has a feature allowing you to drop a `<filename>.mount` file in the systemd `system` directory. Example:

```
/etc/systemd/system/var-lib-docker.mount
```

The file-name has to be formatted a certain way:

> Mount units must be named after the mount point directories they control. For Example: the mount point `/var/lib/docker` must be configured in a unit file `var-lib-docker.mount`. For details about the escaping logic used to convert a file system path to a unit name, see manpage of systemd.unit.
>
> From: https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-auto-mount-a-filesystem-using-systemd/

However, the official documentation says **/etc/fstab** is the recommended approach.

> fstab
>
> Mount units may either be configured via unit files, or via /etc/fstab (see fstab(5) for details). Mounts listed in /etc/fstab will be converted into native units dynamically at boot and when the configuration of the system manager is reloaded. In general, configuring mount points through /etc/fstab is the preferred approach.
>
> docs: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.mount.html

You say you were using an fstab option to remount as read-only after failed mount as read/write, and this doesn't work. I don't recommend using script hacks. This avoids fixing the problem. If the above steps don't resolve your problem, investigate with the package maintainer, or the project developers. See the bottom of FreeDesktop's Debugging page for links to report systemd bugs and a description of what to attach to a bug report:

https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Debugging/

Comment: Hmm, ok. But is there any way to solve this temporarily while I contact the package maintainers? Or to let the mount simply let it fail? (it would prevent start-up when failing some times).

Answer (score 1):

It seems like using a [`.mount`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.mount.html) unit would be a good solution, as suggested by Ryan.

However, if you have already configured a standard service file, and want to keep using that...

The problem is that the default behaviour for a service is to run the `ExecStop` command as soon as the `ExecStart` process stops running. You can prevent that by adding this config to the `.service` file:

```
[Service]
# Stoppable one-shot service (this might not actually be needed, not sure)
# It allows you to specify multiple ExecStart commands, if that's desirable
Type=oneshot

# Useful: This ensures systemd won't automatically stop the service immediately
# after the start command completed.
# It is not recommended for daemons, because it won't notice if the daemon crashes.
RemainAfterExit=yes

# Optional: Will mark the service as successful, even if the script returns an error,
# which will at least allow bootup to continue
ExecStartPost=/bin/true
```

Docs: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html

Finally, I would recommend removing any entry from `/etc/fstab` if systemd is trying to unmount it automatically on shutdown, but you would prefer to unmount it manually using `ExecStop`.